# ExtJs- when clicking on bottom margin of last item, everything deselects

Tags: extjs

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/hmfm9/2/ of my problem

Why is it when i clicked on the margin on the last item everything deselects?

```
new Ext.Container({
   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   items: [{
       xtype: 'dataview',
       selectedItemCls: 'selected',
       itemSelector: 'li',
       selModel: {
          mode: 'SIMPLE'
       },
       tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<ul><tpl for="."><li>{name}</li></tpl></ul>'),
       store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
          fields: ['name'],
          data: [{ name: 'Test1'},{ name: 'Test2'},{name: 'Test3'},{name: 'Test4'},{name: 'Test5'}]
       }),
   }]
})
```

Comment: Because you are clicking outside all elements, but inside their container? (Just a guess...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer this question, all we need is to override the containerclick event of the gridview

```
listeners: {
   containerclick: function(){
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is specified by @Paolo Stefan. Fix may be, remove the css(li:last-child) or change the value from 10 to 0 of margin-bottom in css.

```
li:last-child{ margin-bottom: 0px;}
```

Comment: Do you want that space as well as you problem should be fixed ?